# SSL TLS Failure

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver

I've installed a trusted SSL cert on my apache webserver, but when i use https for my webhooks, there's a TLS failure. Stripe sends the webhooks to verifus.ddns.net:4568/webhook and  it works, but https doesn't work, and chrome gives `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`  when visiting the webhook url instead of a 404 like normal.

What causes this?

Answer (score 0):

The client failed to negotiate a shared SSL/TLS protocol with the server. You should check what protocols your server currently has enabled. Typically, this would only be TLS1.1 and TLS1.2. Then I would check that the client also has the same versions of TLS enabled.